# Problem with running application supported with microsoft .net framework 4.0.30319

Tags: wine, winetricks, dotnet

I have an application which i want to run with wine in my ubuntu. I installed wine properly and also all the dlls and support files. But i am unable to open my application.

It shows always an error To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework 4.0.30319

I don't know how to get rid of this. kindly suggest

Comment: I also have the same error and the framework is indeed installed - really this is a wine support issue - not ubuntu

Comment: Hi, 

I solved that issue with installing all the .net framework dlls one by one. May be you can try as well. It depends on your application which .net framework version it supports.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to install the .NET Framework then in Wine. More information on that can be found here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17886